# How to use arc4random() to change the text in an NSString randomly from a specific text array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cydia

I'm working on a "Commentator" application. I have a few words e.g.. good, nice ok etc. and i want to randomly change an NSString's text to any of these. How is this possible? If not is there any alternative? Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that you have your comments in an `NSArray` object called `comments`

```
NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [comments count];
NSString *randomComment = comments[randomIndex];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Moxy this really helped! I love you awesome helping dudes on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

this might help u

```
NSMutableString *randomizedText = [NSMutableString stringWithString:currentText];

NSString *buffer;
for (NSInteger i = randomizedText.length - 1, j; i >= 0; i--)
{
    j = arc4random() % (i + 1);

buffer = [randomizedText substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
[randomizedText replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1) withString:[randomizedText substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j, 1)]];
[randomizedText replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(j, 1) withString:buffer];
}
```

this gives you a randomizedText using arc4random(). Hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks but this was not really what i was looking for :P